# Create orgmode agenda from remote directory recursively over ssh

Tags: org-mode, eshell

I've set up a vserver with my directory containing various `.txt` files used as Org files and other files.
Now I am trying to get my local Emacs build an agenda gathering all data from the remote files scattered in different subfolders of my remote directory `nexus`.
So I found this

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-files
(mapcar 'abbreviate-file-name
(split-string
(shell-command-to-string "find ~/org -name \"*.org\"")
"\n")))
```

I customized it to

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-files
(mapcar 'abbreviate-file-name
(split-string
(shell-command-to-string "ssh foo@11.111.11.11 \"find ~/nexus -name \"*.txt\"\"")
"\n")))
```

to filter `.txt` files for agenda items (`.txt` files work for my agenda locally - I've managed to do that). But it still won't work.
My guess: I did not write the shell query correctly.
Also, I am wondering if this would be a suited approach to check my agenda remotely from different devices. For example, it is planned to setup orgzly and termux later to also access those files.
Additional info:
The size of the nexus is about a few thousand different files and a few hundred text files with org content stretching for 500 to 5000 lines.

Comment: Have you tried to use Tramp?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for myself

```
(shell-command-to-string "ssh myhost \"find Org -name *.org\"")
```